# Restrict carriage return on writable div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a div writable by adding contentEditable="true".
I want to restrict the text to one line and restrict users to enter multiple lines. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a function to the keypress event on the div and disallow the enter button

```
$("div").keypress(function(event){
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pyeyY/

Comment: The question doesn't have a jQuery tag.

Comment: yeah, i forgot to add a jquery tag, it looks like jquery version is compatible with all the browsers, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
div.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) { e.preventDefault(); }
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3QbCk/